# How can I pass id_token_hint

Tags: blazor-server-side, azure-ad-b2c

I have a blazor application. It is authenticated using Azure AD B2C. The sign in user flow is set to Require ID Token in logout requests. When the user is trying to log out, the following error is received:

> Sorry, but we're having trouble signing you in.
> ...
> The id_token_hint parameter has not been specified in the request.
> Please provide token and try again.

I know that I need to pass id_token_hint as a query parameter, but can't find how exactly this can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-with-magic-link) and [this](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/using-a-jwt-to-invoke-an-azure-ad-b2c-flow-using-id-token-hint-13752ee6d9df).

In both cases, the code to build the magic link is included.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understand correctly, the solution suggests generating a magic link and sending it by email, so the user could click it and log in. But our scenario does not expect such a behavior. Is there a way to pass the id_token_hint during regular sign in process? Or it is not an option? If so, should I just uncheck Require ID Token in the user flow?

Comment: Maybe uncheck? https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/34435

Comment: Hi rbrayb. Could you edit this answer so that it is more self-contained (perhaps by summarising what the links say)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Blazor does not currently send the id_token_hint.  MS have been aware since .Net 5, but are yet to fix it.  There's signs it could be fixed in .Net 8.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/29586